# load dataset from URL not available in R, only load from local: settings problem?

Tags: r, url, import, dataset

I want to import a dataset from a URL. In R studio, environment > import Dataset, I expect the menu to give: From local file.... from web URL.... 
But instead I get a drop down with five choices: From text (base), From text (readr) etc.
I have really no idea. A settings issue?
many thanks. greatings Jan

Comment: All of those options will work with a URL or a local file.

Comment: Thanks. It works indeed. I was too impacient. greetings